# Chained expressions to perform calculations in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite, core-data, nsexpression

First of all: Happy new year :-)

### What I am trying to do

I am trying to divide two attributes in Core Data and then calculate the average of these divisions. The attributes are specified by a key path (e.g. `eur`, `usd`, `aud`).

**Example:**
I have the following data set:

```
date         eur   usd    aud
------------------------------
2010-01-01   0.5   1.0    1.5
2010-01-02   0.6   1.1    1.6
2010-01-03   0.4   1.0    1.3
```

Divide two attributes, e.g. eur / usd with the follwowing results...

```
divide eur / usd:
------------------
2010-01-01   0.5
2010-01-02   0.54
2010-01-03   0.4
```

... then calculate the average of these numbers `(0.5 + 0.54 + 0.4)/3 = 0.48`

### My code

Since I would like to have these calculations performed directly by Core Data, I created the following expressions and fetch request:

```
NSExpression *fromCurrencyPathExpression = [NSExpression
    expressionForKeyPath:fromCurrency.lowercaseString];
NSExpression *toCurrencyPathExpression   = [NSExpression
    expressionForKeyPath:toCurrency.lowercaseString]; 
NSExpression *divisionExpression = [NSExpression
   expressionForFunction:@"divide:by:"
   arguments:@[fromCurrencyPathExpression,
   toCurrencyPathExpression]];
    
NSExpression *averageExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"average:"
   arguments:@[divisionExpression]];

NSString *expressionName = @"averageRate";
NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = 
   [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
expressionDescription.name = expressionName;
expressionDescription.expression = averageExpression;
expressionDescription.expressionResultType= NSDoubleAttributeType;

NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest 
   fetchRequestWithEntityName:NSStringFromClass([self class])];
NSPredicate *predicate =
   [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date >= %@ AND date <= %@",startDate,fiscalPeriod.endDate];
    
request.predicate = predicate;
request.propertiesToFetch = @[expressionDescription];
request.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
     
NSError *error;
NSArray *results = [context 
    executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

### The problem

However, when running the app, it crashes with the error message:

```
Unsupported argument to sum : (
    "eur / usd"
```

What is wrong with my code?
How can I chain the two calculations and have them performed directly in Core Data?

Thank you!

Comment: Here are similar problems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13879025/fetch-aggregate-data-from-nsmanagedobject-using-another-expression-as-argument-t, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985194/performing-multiplication-aggregation-with-coredata-how-to. So it seems just to be unsupported.

Comment: Would it be possible to split the fetch request in two separate requests, one for the division and one for the calculation of the average number?

Comment: Probably. You could execute a fetch request that returns an array with the results of all divisions, and then calculate the average in memory, using key-value-coding (something like `[results valueForKey:@"@avg:..."]`. I cannot test this at this moment, perhaps it helps already, otherwise I will try to give explicit code later...

Comment: Is there a performance hit when calculating the averages in memory instead doing this directly in the database? In my current implementation, I do everything in memory (fetching the data sets, division and aggregation). Since this very slow, I am hoping for a significant improvement in performance when doing this in the data base. Btw: I would really appreciate if you could show me some code on how to do the division in the data base. Thank you!

Comment: I have finally added an answer with some code. You probably figured out a solution yourself in the meantime, but perhaps it is useful. I cannot really comment on the performance question, this is something you have to test and compare.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that "collection" function expressions like `@average` can only be used with key paths, but not in combination with other general expressions, when used as `propertiesToFetch`. I do not have a reference for that, but it is a problem that others have noticed also:

- [Fetch aggregate data from NSManagedObject using another expression as argument to sum: expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13879025/fetch-aggregate-data-from-nsmanagedobject-using-another-expression-as-argument-t)
- [Performing multiplication (aggregation) with CoreData: how to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985194/performing-multiplication-aggregation-with-coredata-how-to)

So you could proceed in two steps: First execute a fetch request that returns an array with the results of all divisions:

```
NSExpression *fromCurrencyPathExpression = [NSExpression
                                            expressionForKeyPath:@"eur"];
NSExpression *toCurrencyPathExpression   = [NSExpression
                                            expressionForKeyPath:@"usd"];
NSExpression *divisionExpression = [NSExpression
                                    expressionForFunction:@"divide:by:"
                                    arguments:@[fromCurrencyPathExpression,
                                    toCurrencyPathExpression]];

NSString *expressionName = @"ratio";
NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription =
[[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
expressionDescription.name = expressionName;
expressionDescription.expression = divisionExpression;
expressionDescription.expressionResultType= NSDoubleAttributeType;

NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Entity"];

request.propertiesToFetch = @[expressionDescription];
request.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;

NSError *error;
NSArray *ratios = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

The result is an array of dictionaries:

```
(lldb) po ratios
(NSArray *) $0 = 0x00000001001170f0 <_PFArray 0x1001170f0>(
{
    ratio = "0.5454545454545454";
},
{
    ratio = "0.4";
},
{
    ratio = "0.5";
}
)
```

Also, with the "-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1" option one can see that the divisions are already executed on the SQLite level:

```
sql: SELECT  t0.ZEUR /  t0.ZUSD FROM ZENTITY t0
```

Then you can compute the average of all ratios in memory, using Key-Value Coding:

```
NSNumber *average = [ratios valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.ratio"];
```

and the result is

```
(lldb) po average
(NSNumber *) $0 = 0x000000010012fd60 0.4818181818181818
```

Comment: Thank you for your great answer, Martin! This is exactly how I did it my self and it works great. I assume that the `valueForKeyPath`command is executed in memory and not in SQL.

Comment: @AlexR: Yes, `ratios` is a plain dictionary which does not have any connections to the database. `valueForKeyPath` operates only on that dictionary.