# Perform operation on two Core Data Attributes with NSExpressions

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsexpression

Things like max, min, and avg can be calculated just fine,

```
NSExpression *maxDate = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"startDate"];
NSExpression *maxDateExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"max:"
                                                            arguments:@[maxDate]];
NSExpressionDescription *maxDateExpressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[maxDateExpressionDescription setName:@"maxDate"];
[maxDateExpressionDescription setExpression:maxDateExpression];
[maxDateExpressionDescription setExpressionResultType:NSDateAttributeType];



[request setPropertiesToFetch:@[maxDateExpressionDescription]];


// Execute the fetch.
NSError *error = nil;

NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (error) {
    // Handle the error.

    NSLog(@"Error!");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Max date is: %@", [objects[0] objectForKey:@"maxDate"]);
]
```

But, given I have "Item" entities, with the price I bought it for and the price I sold it for as attributes, how I calculate the total Profit of all Item entities using NSExpressions?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following expression description computes the price difference for each object:

```
NSExpression *price1Expr = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"price1"];
NSExpression *price2Expr = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"price2"];
NSExpression *profitExpr = [NSExpression
                                    expressionForFunction:@"from:subtract:"
                                    arguments:@[price2Expr, price1Expr]];

NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[expressionDescription setName:@"profit"];
[expressionDescription setExpression:profitExpr];
[expressionDescription setExpressionResultType:NSDoubleAttributeType];

NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Entity"];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:@[expressionDescription]];
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
NSArray *profits = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@", profits);
```

**EDIT:** (The question was edited while I was writing the above answer.) Computing the *sum* of all price differences seems not to be possible with a single fetch request,
see for example [Chained expressions to perform calculations in Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122086/chained-expressions-to-perform-calculations-in-core-data). But you can fetch the array of all price differences, using
the above expression description, and calculate the sum using Key-Value coding:

```
NSArray *profits = result of fetch request
NSNumber *totalProfit = [profits valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.profit"];
NSLog(@"%@", totalProfit);
```

Comment: Hmmm I get this crash error messsage using the above expression description: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid keypath (request for aggregate operation on a toOne-only keypath): purchasePrice'

Comment: @Skyler: I have tested this now and it worked for me. I have added the complete fetch code to the answer.

Comment: @Skyler: Perhaps you can show the definition of your entity and your current code.

Comment: as it turns out the issue was passing an array of size greater than one for the method NSFetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:. I was attempting to perform multiple operations, such as sum all purchase prices, sum all sale prices, etc. If I split the fetch requests' properties to fetch, the application did not crash. Thank you for your help.