# How to multiply two columns and sum it in CoreData?

Tags: ios, core-data, sum, multiple-columns

I have a goods in document and I want to multiply quantity and price of every good in document and sum it.

In mySQL something like this: `SELECT SUM(price * quantity) FROM documentGoods`

Here is my code, but it doesn't work.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetch setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:self.tableName inManagedObjectContext:moc]];
[fetch setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];

NSExpression *multiplyExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"multiply:by:" arguments:@[[NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"quantity"], [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"price"]]];
NSExpressionDescription *expressionMultipliedDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[expressionMultipliedDescription setName:@"multiplied"];
[expressionMultipliedDescription setExpression:multiplyExpression];
[expressionMultipliedDescription setExpressionResultType:NSDecimalAttributeType];

NSExpression *sumExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"sum:" arguments:@[[NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"multiplied"]]];
NSExpressionDescription *expressionSummaryDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[expressionSummaryDescription setName:@"summary"];
[expressionSummaryDescription setExpression:sumExpression];
[expressionSummaryDescription setExpressionResultType:NSDecimalAttributeType];

[fetch setPropertiesToFetch:@[expressionSummaryDescription]];
NSPredicate *searchFilter = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"removed = NO"]]];
[fetch setPredicate:searchFilter];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *objects = [moc executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];
if(objects && [objects count] > 0)
    return [[objects objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"summary"];
return [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithFloat:.0f];
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Stops on [moc executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error]

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: It seems that you cannot "nest" expressions in Core Data fetch requests, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122086/chained-expressions-to-perform-calculations-in-core-data (probably a "duplicate" question).

Comment: CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Non-attribute property passed to sum: sum:(multiplied) with userInfo (null)

Comment: What happens in `controllerDidChangeContent:` ?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar scenario where my entity is "Cart" and has fields price and quantity. To get sum(quantity * price) from cart i used the following code. The last NSLog would log the required total cart price

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Cart" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
request.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;

NSExpressionDescription *productTotalDescr = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[productTotalDescr setName:@"productTotal"];
[productTotalDescr setExpression:[NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"multiply:by:"
                                                    arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                               [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"price"],
                                                               [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"quantity"],
                                                               nil]]];
[productTotalDescr setExpressionResultType:NSInteger64AttributeType];

request.propertiesToFetch = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:productTotalDescr, nil];

NSError *err = nil;
NSArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&err];
NSLog(@"%@",[results valueForKeyPath:@"productTotal"]);
```