# Fetching counts of to-many Core Data relationships with NSExpression

Tags: core-data, nsexpression

My Core Data model has a `Note` entity with a to-many relationship to a `Link` entity, accessed through a `links` property on `Note`.

I'm trying to fetch the count of the `links` property for each note in Core Data. To do so, I followed the example at the link below, but I'm getting an unexpected result.
[Chained expressions to perform calculations in Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122086/chained-expressions-to-perform-calculations-in-core-data)

Here's how I'm configuring the fetch request and related expression descriptions:

```
// Create the expression description that should return the link count for each note.
NSExpression *linksExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"links"];
NSExpression *countExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"count:" arguments:@[linksExpression]];
NSExpressionDescription *linkCountExpressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
linkCountExpressionDescription.name = @"linkCount";
linkCountExpressionDescription.expression = countExpression;
linkCountExpressionDescription.expressionResultType = NSInteger32AttributeType;

// Execute a fetch request that should return an array of dictionaries, each with a single "linkCount" key.
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Note"];
fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = @[linkCountExpressionDescription];
NSArray *countsArray = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
```

The SQLite store I'm working with contains 1000 notes, so I expect to get an array of 1000 dictionaries, each containing a `LinkCount` key and the count of its `links` relationship. Instead, I get a single dictionary that gives me the total count of all links.

What should I do differently to get the link counts for each note?